# No pics in my PDF created with PdfKit on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, pdfkit

I've an app which works fine in development and on my current production server.

I want to move it to FREE heroku (basic config: 1 dyno, 1 worker).

Unfortunately, the pdf generation (**using PdfKit**) is ok BUT without the pictures **defined in my CSS**.

I've followed a lot of tips including:

- http://blog.mattgornick.com/using-pdfkit-on-heroku
- http://jguimont.com/post/2627758108/pdfkit-and-its-middleware-on-heroku
- http://code-fu.pl/blog/2011/05/17/pdfkit-heroku

Thoughts?

---

Found a workaround but I am still eager to know a better option:

- I duplicated my view: one dedicated for html, another for pdf.
- I removed all css using pics and put it in a separate file, included only in the view dedicated for html
- finally, I inserted the css ***in the view*** dedicated to the pdf:

  `.foo { background-image:url(<%= Rails.root %>/public/images/bar.png) }`

Very Ugly but works so please tell me if you've better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I answered my needs with:

- Just one single view file
- Just one css file

The trick was to pass the proper base_url to the css file **dynamically**, given I expected a pdf or html.

I decided to use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). Style compiles css in a different manner, given the base-url I provide in the DOM. This base-url is generated by a helper.

---

Here were my steps:

- changed my `style.css` to `style.less`
- Added to my view:

> ```
> <%= stylesheet_link_tag "style.less", :rel => "stylesheet/less" %>
>
> <script id="base_url" type="text/javascript" data="<%= assets_path %>"></script>
>
> <%= javascript_include_tag "less.min.js" %>
> ```

- In my helper:

> ```
>   def assets_path
>     if request.fullpath.include? ".pdf"
>       "#{Rails.root.join('public',"images","pictos")}"
>     else
>       "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}/images/pictos"
>     end
>   end
> ```

- and in my `style.less`:

> ```
> @base_url: `document.getElementById('base_url').getAttribute('data')`;
>
> .foo { background-image:~"url(@{base_url}/bar.png)" }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue with the way the url's are specified in the css.  As I recall, they should be file system absolute paths.  What does your css look like?

Comment: well, absolute paths won't be the same in dev and prod so I'd need at least 2 css files which is not acceptable or any better than my current work around

Comment: Generate the css with rails so you can include a call to Rails.root for the path